# How to fill 2 column cards from Python loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, flask, semantic-ui

[image]Im trying to loop over a Python list to fill out rows of 2 centered Semantic UI cards but not getting how to correctly fill the second card in the row. At the moment I have in my code the string "hey" but before that I had the 'user' but of course was getting the same user twice : /

```
     [![enter image description here][1]][1]<div class="ui two column centered grid">
        {% for user in users %}
          <div class="four column centered row">
            <!-- card 1 -->
            <div class="column"><div class="ui card">
              <div class="image">
                <img src="/static/images/matthew.png">
              </div>
              <div class="content">
                <a class="header" href="{{ url_for('show', id=user.id)}}">{{ user.first_name }}</a>
                <div class="meta">
                  <span class="date">Joined in 2013</span>
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                  {{ user.first_name }} is a surfer living in Aguadilla.
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="extra content">
                <a>
                  <i class="user icon"></i>
                  22 Friends
                </a>
              </div>
            </div></div>
            <!-- card 2 -->
            <div class="column">hey</div>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
```

Comment: Check the card 2 elements in your browser development tools, it should be ignored due to some style issues.

Comment: before sending data to template you could convert data in flat `[A, B, C, D, ...]` to 2-dimensional `[ [A, B], [C, D], ...]` and then you could use two `for`-loops - `for row in data: for item in row: ...`

Comment: for single `for`-loop I see only method with `for i in range(0, len(users), 2): users[i], users[i+1]`. Eventually with `zip()` - `for user1, user2 in zip(users[0::2], users[1::2]):`

Comment: I went with it and worked. Thanks furas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have flat list `[0, 1, 2, 3, ...]` instead of `[ [0,1], [2,3], ...]` then you can try to use slicing with `zip()` to convert it.

Using `users[0::2]` you can get even users `(0,2,4, ...)`,

Using `users[1::2]` you can get odd users `(1,3,5, ...)`

And using it with `zip()` you can create pairs `(0,1), (2,3), ...` which you can use to create rows with two cards.

```
for user1, user2 in zip(users[0::2], users[1::2]):
    # ... create card1 with user1 ...
    # ... create card2 with user2 ...
```

---

I don't know if `zip()` can be used in template but eventually you can use this method to create list `[ [0,1], [2,3], ...]` before sending it to template.

Comment: Thanks a ton, instead of using zip in the template I did the loop inside the routing file and passed along a variable with the new list to the view.